# Is this proof with logarithmic exponentials correct?

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms

I was unsure of this proof and some of the log rules I applied, could you check my proof and tell me if this proof is correct and if not, then what specifically is incorrect about the proof?

[image: Logarithm claim to prove.]

$\implies \bigl( \log_c b \bigr) \log a = \bigl( \log_c a \bigr) \log b$

$\implies \Bigl( \frac{\log b}{\log c} \Bigr) \log a = \Bigl( \frac{\log a}{\log c} \Bigr) \log b$

$\log c$, on both sides, cancel out (?):

$\implies (\log b) \log a = (\log a) \log b$

$\implies \bigl( \log b - \log a \bigr) \log a = \log b$

$\implies \Bigl( \frac{\log b}{\log a} \Bigr) \log a = \log b$

$\implies \dfrac{\log b}{\log a} = \dfrac{\log b}{\log a}$

Hence the left hand side $=$ right hand side of the equation. I realise I haven't used proof writing language or stated the rules I have applied, I am just trying to wrap my head around how to show this proof first. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: The question would be more readable if you used $\LaTeX$. Which rules are you unsure of and why?

Comment: Please spend a few minutes learning how to typeset LaTeX.  As they are written, your equations areally difficult to parse.  Here is a brief tutorial:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The order in which you have written the equations is essentially backwards:  you have begun with the conclusion and finished with a simple tautology.

Comment: sorry give me a min ill make edits to format.

Comment: Added latex, @Sammy: I guess I was just trying to show they were equal directly. I assumed by making the left hand side equal the right hand side they were then equal. If this is not the correct way to show this proof can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your line "$(\log b - \log a) \log a = \log b$" is wrong but can be ignored.  More seriously, your proof is upside down: you start from what you are asked to prove and end up with an obvious equality when you should start with something true and end up with what you want to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going through the right motions, more-or-less.  I have three comments.

1. The step where you subtract logarithms neither follows from the line above or the line below.  It seems like a "mutation" in a an otherwise logically connected sequence of equations.
2. <strike>You are dividing by various quantities that could be zero ($\log 1 = 0$, for example).  You have to justify how to deal with special cases if they arise.</strike>  I reread the hypotheses in the statement.  With $a, b, c > 1$, there are no division by zero issues.
3. As mentioned in the comments, the argument essentially flows in the wrong direction.  Fortunately, for each of your implications, the converse statement is also true.  So, to polish the proof, you would write those equations in the reverse order.  Begin with something obviously true, and deduce finally the statement quoted at the top.

---

Here is what it looks like (modulo explaining how each equation follows from the previous).

$$
\begin{align}
\log b \log a &= \log a \log b \\
\frac{\log b}{\log c} \log a &= \frac{\log a}{\log c} \log b \\
\log_c b \cdot \log a &= \log_c a \cdot \log b \\
\log \bigl( a^{\log_c b} \bigr) &= \log \bigl( b^{\log_c a} \bigr) \\
a^{\log_c b} &= b^{\log_c a}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just one question about your first step, shouldn't the second step be put as the first step since the first step doesn't establish that log b and log a are of base c?

Comment: The first step is a good starting point because of the commutative property of multiplication:  both sides of the equation have to be equal.  In order to pass to the second, I divide both sides of the equation by the positive number $\log c$.